# How to use Javascript to determine where a user is typing on webpage and react accordingly

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am new to javascript, and am writing a simple bookmarklet for a webpage that has a text input section. Basically what I need is a way to execute the following-

```
if ( ! (text_section).onkeydown ) { 

     do whatever

}
```

I need to ignore key-events when the user is typing inside an input field but otherwise trigger key-events for the entire page whenever the user presses a key. I do know that onkeydown is an event listener/handler I'm just trying to explain what I need to do more accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an *id* for your text-section, for example "myTextSection". Apply the *addEventListener* to the whole *document*. If the *target* is anything else, than the textfield, *do whatever*:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if(event.target !== document.getElementById("myTextSection")){
         //do whatever;
    }
});
```

Note that this behaviour might be irritating for users, that navigate by keyboard (for example *tab* and *space* keys) through your page. So you might want to add another if statement checking whether the *event.keyCode* is alphanumeric. In this case the keyCode is in the ranges

- [47-58] (for 0-9),
- [64-91] (for A-Z) or
- [96-123](for a-z)

Answer (score 0):

You should add an event listener to the target element:

```js
targetElement.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
 // do something
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

It is also possible to use `onkeydown` property:

```js
targetElement.onkeydown = (e) => {
  // do something
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeydown

Comment: To exclude key events triggered by typing in inputs, you can check `event.target.tagName` and ignore `INPUT` and `TEXTAREA`.